# What can be concluded about a domain and range based on how many points it passes through?

Tags: geometry

I have a homework question that asks:

What can you conclude about the domain and range of a vertical line at x=5 and what does it mean if it passes through 2 points, 1 point, or no points?

I believe that the domain is 5 and the range is all real numbers. But, I don't understand the relation to the number of points.

Comment: A *function* has a domain (set of inputs) and range (set of outputs). Neither of these is a single number, but rather a set of numbers (like an interval or union of intervals). What you've described is the equation of a vertical line, and it's not clear how that has anything to do with any function.

Comment: @SammyBlack: The word "function" does not appear anywhere in the OP. In this case, the main object is not a function but a correspondence.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Exactly. I was pointing out that *domain* and *range* are attributes of functions, and there isn't one to be found (not in any standard way, anyway).